# Set selection in UITextView after UITableView reloadData?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have placed an `UITextView` inside the `UITableViewCell`. Once the user tap on some button, I will call the `[UITableView relodaData]` to update the contents inside the `UITextView`.

My aim is to set the selection inside the `UITextView` after reloadData get called. Is there any callbacks method is available for `[UITableView reloadData]` method just like `performBatchUpdates` available for 
`UICollectionView`.

Comment: I can't understand ,what type of selection do you want??

Comment: No there is no such method exist. You need to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or other `UITableViewDataSource` method to achieve what you want.

Comment: Achieve using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If not, use some `BOOL` variables.

Comment: @h.kishan : I want to put cursor foucs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading table view does not normally resign first responder. Must be something in your code, for example in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Anyway, to restore lost focus, keep track of which textView is editing (if there is only one, it's much simpler), remember it before calling `reloadData` and restore cursor after that.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    _currentEditingTextView = textView;
}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    _currentEditingTextView = nil;
}
- (void)yourUpdate {
    UITextView *editingTextView = _currentEditingTextView; 
    [tableView reloadData];
    [editingTextView performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) 
                           withObject:nil 
                           afterDelay:0.1]
}
```

Also, if you need to update only one cell, do that by `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method. Or, if you need only update textview's text, do that directly:

```
((YourCellClass *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourRow inSection:0]]).textView.text = ...;
```

Comment: `Reloading table view does not normally resign first responder. `

- If you mean it does not resign the textView as a firstResponder, then you are wrong.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190184/3231194