# How do I stop UITextView from resigning first responder/closing keyboard when selecting another UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have an editable UITextView, then a UITextView that is just for selecting. When I'm writing things in the first UITextView, I sometimes want to reference the other UITextView to copy text, then paste it into the first, but when I select the second UITextView, the first resigns first responder/closes the keyboard.

Is there a way to make UITextView not resign first responder when selecting another UITextView?

Comment: simply neglect the becomefirst responder if it is the second textview

Comment: can u show ur delegate methods ?

Comment: would `textViewShouldEndEditing` -> false work?

Comment: @Mr.T I'm not calling it myself, it automatically occurs.

Comment: incase of responder it occurs automatically, but incase of keyboard I guess its not. YOu need to call endEditing to hide the keyboard, else the keyboard stays there even you select other text view.

Comment: @Mr.T Huh? How do I call endEditing?

Comment: You can simply call [self.view endEditing:YES]; By calling this you are hiding the keyboard which you dont want. Look out for this line of code in yours and see if it is getting hit when u tap on second text view

Answer (score 3):

As @Tim mentioned in the comment, the following should work:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This resolves my top-priority issue wherein when there's an inevitable reloadData() call, the textView resigns as firstResponder (keyboard dismisses).